# CMake INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for IMPORTED target with CONFIG

Tags: cmake, conan

I have an IMPORTED target which comes from a config package generated by conan. Since conan creates packages for the build type specified in the build_type of the profile, I have added CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG to Release, so that even if I compile a Debug build of my project, I can still use Config files generated with conan using a Release profile.

This works fine for all the targets in my project. include directories are set correctly, libraries link correctly. except for one case:

I have an INTERFACE target which I use to use only the include directories of an IMPORTED target if one option is set, or use the whole target.

```
add_library(deTracing INTERFACE)

# Get include directories of Tracy::TracyClient target
get_target_property(TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES Tracy::TracyClient INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

# Include the directories unconditionally
target_include_directories(deTracing INTERFACE ${TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

# Some debug stuff
message(status ${TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
add_custom_target(genexdebug COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "${TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")

# If ENABLE_PROFILING is set, link to the library
if(ENABLE_PROFILING)
  target_link_libraries(deTracing INTERFACE Tracy::TracyClient)
  target_compile_definitions(deTracing INTERFACE ENABLE_PROFILING)
endif()
```

The issue is that TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES is a generator expression with this content
`$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/home/seddi/.conan/data/tracy/0.9/_/_/package/913e5b8c3a7b64b23fdaa63b58e3915a742a1112/include>`, which is what I can expect, it just contains the include directory for the release config.

But when this expression is evaluated in a Debug build, it just collapses to an empty string, even though I have set the CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG to Release, so it doesn't set any include directories.

I am out of ideas of how I set the correct INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES to deTracing target.

Edit:
According to CMake, the MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_ property is followed when evaluating properties of IMPORTED targets. I have modified deTracing to be an IMPORTED target, yet still doesn't work.

```
add_library(deTracing INTERFACE IMPORTED)

get_target_property(TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES Tracy::TracyClient INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
set_property(
  TARGET deTracing
  PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
  APPEND) # ${TRACY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

get_target_property(deTracing_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES deTracing INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("deTracing INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: ${deTracing_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")

add_library(TestTarget INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(TestTarget INTERFACE deTracing)
get_target_property(TestTarget_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES TestTarget INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("TestTarget INCLUDE DIRECTORIES: ${TestTarget_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")
```

This snippet produces the following output

```
[cmake] deTracing INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES: $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/home/seddi/.conan/data/tracy/0.9/_/_/package/913e5b8c3a7b64b23fdaa63b58e3915a742a1112/include>
[cmake] TestTarget INCLUDE DIRECTORIES: TestTarget_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES-NOTFOUND
```

which shows that `deTracing` is able to set the correct INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for the Release config, but then is unable to set them on TestTarget, even though deTracing is an IMPORTED target.

Comment: Unfortunate. I suppose you could hack around it be using [`string(SUBSTRING)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#substring) to strip the generator expression wrapper.

Comment: Sure I could do that. But I feel like this is a bug in CMake or something. In their documentation they say that $<$<CONFIG:Release>:...> should follow the CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG property for IMPORTED targets...

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#configuration-expressions

Comment: If it's a bug, I suggest you create a [mre] and then create [an issue ticket on the CMake GitLab](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues). But is it really a bug? The exact wording is: "_The mapping in MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG> is also considered by this expression when it is evaluated on a property of an IMPORTED target._" (emphasis on "IMPORTED") What if you change your `deTracing` target to be `IMPORTED` as well? Would that work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, Ill add the information to the question

Comment: In your `TestTarget_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, I don't think that's how `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` works. I don't think it also includes those of its dependencies when you get the target property. If you really want to check the compile command that gets generated, then do precisely that. If you're using Unix Makefiles or a Ninja generator, you can use [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html).

Comment: It includes the dependencies ones since they are INTERFACE. I have already checked the compile command for a particular TU and of course, it doesn't have the tracy includes. The question is, why?

Comment: Did you check it for the real thing (instead of your little test) after changing `deTracing` to also be `IMPORTED`, making sure to do a fresh reconfigure (`--fresh`)?

Comment: Actually, I tried in my real case and it doesn't work. But if I change TestTarget to be SHARED and just do `target_link_libraries(TestTarget PRIVATE deTracing)` it works for TestTarget.  Note that TestTarget and deTracing are in the same file. But in my real cases, I link to deTracing from another files (should behave correctly though)

Comment: Okay, the documentation for IMPORTED targets says IMPORTED targets have directory scope! That explains why it is not working 
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries

Comment: So if you add `GLOBAL` or move the declaration it works? I don't quite grasp how that's relevant :P

Comment: Adding GLOBAL solved the issue. So the summarize, I have an add_subdirectory(deTracing), with the contents shown here. Then I have add_subdirectory(OtherTarget), which uses deTracing. But deTracing is out of scope in OtherTarget subdirectory, so basically instead of linking to deTracing target, it was trying to link to some deTracing.a, and of course without any information about INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES

Comment: @jjcasmar this would've been easily fixed if you'd include the whole `CMakeLists.txt` and additional information regarding this. I suggest editting the question to include the full scope of information and creating an answer for people who might be looking for similar answers.

Comment: Including the whole CMakeLists was complex, as its a big project and I wasn't expecting the issue to be about the project layout. Ill edit the question and provide more information now we now what the issue is, so future users can find this useful